# Android phone water damage or changed setting?

Tags: volume-control, microphone, water-damage

**TL;DR:** Recently I dropped my phone into water and ever since then I've been having 2 problems. The display has some darker spots, but they are clearing out so I don't even pay attention to them and the microphone volume is extremely low. You can barely hear what I scream to the phone. I've been looking for ways to increase or boost my microphone volume but I haven't found anything. I've tried the "secret" dial pad codes, of which none worked - the code is deleted from the dial pad and nothing shows up and some applications that let you increase your voice volume - the volume was set to 5 by default and did not change at all. The phone model is Huawei Ascend Y511.

**My question is:** is there a way to increase the volume back at it's normal or should I orient at buying a new one?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a bluetooth headset.  The reason is this: if your microphone is damaged, the bluetooth headset should work just fine.  If there is an input volume setting gone wrong, using a bluetooth headset will not fix the problem.  This tells you if you want to look at replacing your phone or do you want to look for a setting to boost the microphone gain.